# rpm/yum: how yum update works internally with regard to overlapping files and unexpected termination of yum

Tags: rpm, yum, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I started to wonder how it works internally.

Let's make it simple so both the old and new versions of Hello package have two files inside: /etc/hello.conf and /usr/bin/hello. The old one is already installed, and I am doing "yum update."

When the files of the new versions are copied to the directories, the old should have been gone. Anyway, the old files shall be lost.

However, the following page appears to say that the removal of old package follows the installation of the new one:

https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Scriptlets/#ordering

Besides, one more thing made me wonder is, what if the yum update command is unexpectedly terminated? I haven't seen that I have lost the old one by just pushing "Ctrl + C."

How does "yum update" work with regard to the files that overlap? How does it protect users from losing the old one when the yum command is terminated in the middle?